# How to get specific row of a matrix inside a cell without the use of another variable?

Tags: matlab, row, cell

I have a cell

```
T = 

[13x2 double]
```

When I look into the cell, I am getting following results

```
T{1,1}

ans =

 2     1
 3     2
 4     3
 7     4
11     5
12     6
17     7
18     8
24     9
27    10
31    11
32    12
34    13
```

When I am trying to access only first row, I am getting the following error.

```
T{1,1}(:1)

    T{1,1}(:1)
     |
    Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Is there is any way in Matlab, where I can access  only the first row without the use of another variable(i.e in one line of code).

Comment: Try this `T{1}(1,:)`.

Comment: Its working thank you